# Send audio from Node backend to frontend

Tags: node.js, ajax, audio, binary, fetch

I have Node/Express server set up in which several thousand audio files are stored within the src folder. I currently have a route set up that sends JSON data in the response object. I wish to also send an mp3 audio file that can be parsed at the front end and be converted to an audio object. I cannot figure out how to encode the audio file such that it may be sent. I have looked into Blobs (these don't seem to be possible in Node) and converting the binary file into a string that may be sent as part of the response body.

Any ideas as to how this may be possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can directly send the audio file with something like:

```js
res.sendFile(__dirname, "/src/audioFile.mp3");
```

Or you could Base64 encode the audio file for your frontend to parse:

```js
fs.readFile("./src/audioFile.mp3", function(err, result) {
  res.send(result.toString("base64"));
});
```

Comment: Thank you, given I am trying to send multiple files in one response, the latter method is ideal

Comment: @Ben great! Were you able to work it out?

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by @code, you can implement this in your Express app:

```
res.sendFile(__dirname, "/src/audioFile.mp3");
```

On your frontend, you can follow these steps. Here's an example using MUI CardMedia:

```
async getAudio() {
  const response = await api.get(`/endpoint`, {
    responseType: "blob",
  });
  return response.data;
}

const [pipelineAudioFile, setPipelineAudioFile] = useState<any>(null); 

useEffect(() => {
  const audio = await getAudio(id);
  const url = URL.createObjectURL(audio);
  setPipelineAudioFile(url);
 }, []);

{pipelineAudioFile && 
  <CardMedia
    component="audio"
    controls
    src={pipelineAudioFile}
  />
}
```